# Run OS X command from within iOS Simulator

Tags: macos, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Is it possible to run an OS X command from an iOS app running in the simulator?

This is only for testing and debugging, clearly it wouldn't go in a finished app!

I've tried using `Process.Start("/usr/bin/grep")`, but the simulator just logs:

> dyld: program was built for Mac OS X and cannot be run in simulator

Playing around with `ProcessStartInfo` options has also brought no joy, and I can't think of anything else.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to run Mac program from iOS app.

Comment: You could start a little web server on OS X and call a web service method from your iOS app which will execute your app.

Comment: The `system` function from C didn't work for me either, same error message. Did you get any further here?